# MongoDB: Can I use my shared IP Address in mongoDB whitelist?

Tags: mongodb, ip, ip-address, shared-hosting, dedicated-server

I am using a shared ip address which keeps changing. every time I search from real ip checked it continuously giving me different than other websites. But first 7 digits keeps still. Last 3 digits becomes different than other one. Now, Is there any way I can use this IP address in my mongoDB whitelist?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a CIDR-notated range of IP addresses.  https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/ provides a few more details.

"The Internet provides online tools for converting a range of IP addresses to CIDR, such as http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr."

Comment: I didn't try that but does it work for CIDR-notated range of IP addresses? Have you tried it?

Comment: The MongoDB documentation states: "Atlas only allows client connections to the cluster from entries in the project’s whitelist. Each entry is either a single IP address or a CIDR-notated range of addresses. "